# Using FLOW -Trigger: When a file is created in a folder is getting failed?

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow

Created a flow while a file is uploaded to a document library, it is getting failed? But for the item created in a list, the flow is working fine don't know why it is not triggered for file upload.

[image]

[image]

Any workaround?

Comment: do you see any errors in log (Run History)?

Comment: In run-history it is not even started. [no log present] when I click on Learn more link, I see the trigger failed message.

Comment: can you post the screenshot of steps so that i can try it with my tenant

Comment: Added the screenshot, pls check.@AkshayRandive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the flow is working fine at my end, are you uploading file to correct folder? or just on root of document library?

[image]

[image]

**Update**: there are 2 triggers for File upload event.(refer above image)

1. triggers when you upload file to root document library
2. will trigger when you upload file to some folder already present in document
   library.

So if you are uploading file to root you need to change trigger to 1st in above screenshot if you are uploading in some folder in Document library user trigger 2

Comment: Just at the root of document library, do they make any difference ?

Comment: updated in answer

Comment: Did that helped you?

Comment: Yes, definitely, i accepted the answer, any idea about moving video files using flow, i am getting error.